# Xamarin Forms: ImageSource.FromUri not display

Tags: ios, iphone, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list of items, each item has an image (download from a remote server) like this:

```
var image = new Image
            {
                WidthRequest = 44,
                HeightRequest = 44,
            };
            image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("ImageUrl"));
```

Almost all images are displayed fine in iPhone 5S and 6+ (simulator/real device).

However, there is an image which is not displayed on iPhone 6+ (simulator/read device). I tried not setting Width and Height Request but it didn't solve the problem.

This is the info of the exceptional image:

```
Size: 9KB (12KB on disk)
Dimension: 608 x 369
Color Space: RGB
Color Profile: Generic RGB Profile
Alpha Channel: Yes
```

Thank you for helping!

EDIT 1: After some experiments, it is a very intermittent problem and NOT specific to iPhone 6+. Sometimes the image appears, sometimes it does not. At the time being I cannot reproduce the bug.

I am pretty sure it is not an layout/ordering issue (I replaced the odd item with another one and it was good). It is not an image size/dimension issue (I replaced the odd image with another image and it was NOT displayed either).

My conclusion up to this point is the URL is causing problem. Anybody experiencing the same issue can try the answer from Kowalski.

Comment: Is it a resource image or remote url image?

Comment: It is an online image.

Comment: Is url correct? Did you try to experiment with Image.Aspect property?

Comment: The url is correct. The image is displayed normally on an iPhone 5s.
I have tried all 3 Aspect properties like you suggested but the problem still persists on iPhone 6+.
Btw, all other images are displayed perfectly and their sizes, dimensions are quite similar to the odd image.

Comment: You could fill a bug then on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and attach the image which is not working.

Comment: I will do it after trying all possible solutions. Thank you.

Comment: What is ImageUrl? Is it s string set the the url? When you do a binding you may need to actually be binding to an ImageSource Instead of a string.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion James. I am sure I set the images correctly since it displays on iPhone 5s. My app actually has 2 screens, the 1st one displays a list of items with a small logo (the image we are talking about), the 2nd one display the details of the items with a bigger logo. On the 1st screen I used Binding, on the 2nd screen I used `Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(raffle.ImageUrl))` 
All the logos display correctly on iPhone 5s. However, on iPhone 6+, the odd logo doesn't display at all on both screens.

Comment: ImageSource.FromUri returns an UriImageSource. Have you tried to change the value for instance for CachingEnabled on this object before setting control's source? http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.UriImageSource/

Comment: Thanks Massimo for your suggestion. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the bug now. I have added my experience in the EDIT 1 of my question.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced with same issue. It's about encoding the URL. You can fix it either common(PCL) project or iOS project via [custom renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/).

All to do is:

```
string encodedURL = Uri.EscapeDataString(yourUrl);
```

and use `encodedURL` as image source.